# When will we get a newsletter?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed

Every site that I know of has a weekly newsletter- except GFH SE. For those who don't know, a newsletter normally contains the top questions from this week, the top two from the last week, and any recent unanswered questions. The newsletters are generated automatically, so I don't see any reason we shouldn't have one. I was wondering when will we get one. I looked at [the newsletter list](http://stackexchange.com/newsletters), but we're not there. When will we get one?

Comment: It's been over three weeks and still no newsletter.

Comment: I'll look into when automated newsletters start coming out for a site. There's no need to bring this up to MSO at this time.

Comment: Now that we have a newsletter - this is the way I know to start getting it - There is probably an easier way, but this works - click on your name, then network profile, then subscriptions to add the newsletter.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sorry about the delay here. Newsletters have to be manually setup, apparently, and especially with recent weather, it was something that rather slipped the mind to bring up.

There is now a Genealogy Newsletter. Additionally, we have configured this for future sites so that it is now automatically setup ~7 days after public beta starts. Thanks to Emmett for setting it up and also doing the automation!

Comment: Yes, the newsletter is now there, but it is not yet listed among the newsletters. I presume it takes a day or so to get listed. But if you type into the search box: "genealogy", then it will show up in the search results and you can subscribe. Also, I saw it as an "ad" in the right column of a question page at GFH Q&A.

Comment: It popped up immediately for me. It's listed in the "life" category.

Answer (score 5):

Now that I have "discovered" the Newsletter page (thanks @Luke), it seems the most accessible way for a casual user to decide whether a particular site is for her. The list of good questions is clean and far less intimidating (for a non-member) than the standard front page.

Which I believe is an argument for having the newsletter available early in the beta. If members are promoting the site, then a link to the latest newsletter would be a good introduction.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with the sentiment that we should have a newsletter. We should also continue to refine our 'about' and our 'faq' (other places newbies go since it's on the header), as well as make the 'brochure' mentioned in [Q1259](https://genealogy.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1259/should-we-create-a-one-page-advertising-flyer) and do the publicity recommended in [Q1210](https://genealogy.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1210/coordinating-publicity).

For those already active, don't forget you can 'subscribe' to tags and it will send you mail summarizing q&a activity on those tags. Tags also each have their own info page, and we need to flesh out those pages as well since newbies might have particular interests like Germany or DNA or ...