# Should we create a one-page advertising flyer?

Tags: discussion

I am going to attend a [local genealogical seminar](http://www.smcgs.org/temporary/fall_2012_seminar.pdf) this weekend, and was thinking it would be a good opportunity to advertise this site. If I can arrange it, I can say a few words about it to the audience, but it would also be good, I think, to have a one page flyer that people could take with them.

I am thinking that others, faced with similar opportunities, might also be able to use the same flyer. My sense is that it should have the following information on it:

1. A paragraph describing the scope and purpose of the site
2. A link to the site
3. A list of some representative questions to give people an idea about the sorts of things they can find on the site.

Do you all think this is a reasonable idea, and, if so, how should we go about making this thing? (I am happy to print them out.)

**UPDATE**

I made a draft flyer based on examples from Robert Cartaino's answer. Here it is.

[image: Sample flyer]

**UPDATE 2**

The MS Word source for this file is [here](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/0336h6ztsahpn42/TdgmwHDtlV/genealogy-stack-exchange-flyer.docx).

Comment: At the risk of hijacking your sensible proposal, I suggest that this is exactly the purpose that would be served by the Newsletter (if we had one -- see http://meta.genealogy.stackexchange.com/q/1196/70)

Comment: I think this is a great idea. If I would have had one, I would have left it on the table with the other flyers at my local genealogical meeting (~90 attendees in the room).

Comment: Let's have a design contest. Post your idea as an answer and vote for the pictures you like. Similar to Photography's Picture of the Week contest. The top-voted picture will become our new advertising flyer!

Comment: Nice job, GeneG

Comment: Thanks! I have the word/PDF versions of it that I can make available for future modification & reuse. How best to share them?

Comment: @GeneGolovchinsky - If you're on Gmail, you could upload it as a Google Doc, then make it public (anyone with the link can view) and then [edit] your post to include that link. Then anyone can grab a copy, print it out themselves, or share the link with others. Nice work!

Comment: @jmort253 I added a dropbox link to the [Word Doc of the flyer](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/0336h6ztsahpn42/TdgmwHDtlV/genealogy-stack-exchange-flyer.docx) to the question.

Comment: Excellent! This would also work on websites if an HTML version could be made up, with hyperlinks from the two urls and the image. You'd have to put the text above and below the image into a table to get the width right.

Answer (score 6):

The timing is tight, but a simple method of promoting your community is having these  one-page flyers available to hand out to interested folks at events.

Time seems to be an issue, so I dug up a few designs I've seen used in the past. It's basically a logo with a bit of copy in a Word document. Unfortunately, as a new site, you do not yet have a custom logo, but the Stack Exchange logos can be found here:

[**Stack Exchange Logos**](http://stackexchange.com/about/logos)

Here is some copy that describes what we do:

[**About Genealogy Stack Exchange**](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/about)

You can use our logos for this particular even, but be sure to follow our [Trademark Guidance](http://stackexchange.com/legal/trademark-guidance) with respect to the logo use. And if you use extensive text from our /about pages or other sources on this site, please send me a copy so I can "approve" it for use. Thanks.

[image: http://gis.stackexchange.com/]  [image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Robert! I will create a draft later today & will attach a copy to this question, unless you suggest a better way to get it to you.

Comment: Great! Have fun at the event and let me know if you need anything. Email is better for correspondence. My email address is in my profile — http://meta.genealogy.stackexchange.com/users/31/robert-cartaino

Comment: UPDATE — Okay, the flyer looks good and everything is a go on this end.

Answer (score 3):

I know I'm a bit late to the party, nevertheless here is my submission. The screenshot is of the highest-voted questions on the site to reflect the quality of questions being asked. I also added a tree illustration to the background (the [source EPS](http://123freevectors.com/vector-colorful-tree/#) itself has text granting permission for its use.)

A [PDF of the flyer](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/1217522/gfh_flyer.pdf) can be downloaded directly for high-quality printouts.

[image: GFH Flyer Preview]

Comment: I like the polished look.

Answer (score 2):

One place to start is with the text from [Q1210's Q&A](https://genealogy.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1210/coordinating-publicity) . I beleive the 'press release' section was intended to be like an eBrochure. I think it should be augmented with maybe a little tutorial on 'how to get started' in more a step-by-step approach with the links spelled out. e.g.

1. Go to the info page at https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/about to learn about this site and go to http://stackexchange.com/about to learn about stack exchange in general
2. Read the faq at https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/faq to find our more about what is appropriate. Note the site is new and still in beta. If you things aren't clear, you can help us make it better with your cold eyes review. Tell us what to improve. Contribute the improvements directly.
3. Go to https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/users/login to 'join'. It's free! If you already have a login with stackexchange, you can link genealogy. If you don't have an account you can create one, and you can use single signon your google, facebook, or yahoo accounts if you don't want yet another password to remember
4. Go to https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions and look at the questions being asked. You can look at the 'Tags' tab to see the categories. Don't dismay if you don't see questions or categories for your interests. You can add them yourself! It will help others with your enthusiasms find and help each other.
5. Answer questions. If you see a question you know the answer to - answer it! If you don't know the answer but have a suggestion on how the original poster (the person who asked the question) can find the answer - then answer the question with that suggestion.
6. Ask your own questions by hitting the 'ask question' tab. Others will help you get your answers - that is the whole purpose of the site.
7. If you have questions about how the site works, or what to contribute to helping make the site better - then explore the 'meta' site at https://genealogy.meta.stackexchange.com/about

My reasoning for spelling it out in a step by step is that many people feel more comfortable (and therefore more likely to do it) with this method, especially the less computer literate. Many accomplished genealogists are more comfortable with paper and with searching the internet; not necessarily with 'changing the internet'. This is particularly true of retirees who have the time to go to the library, go to archives, go to the cemetery. My experience has been they are also the ones more likely to go in person to the society meetings. I think that audience would greatly benefit from this site, and we would greatly benefit from their participation.